# Get Relationship for the Author of the Latest Comment

Tags: views, 8, comments

In a Node view, I am trying to group the latest comments by the author's `field_last_name`, but I am having difficulty adding this field.

I tried using the the "Last comment" and "Last comment author" relationship, but they both don't appear to work. (Neither exposes the user fields or the "Comment: Author" relationship.)

Am I missing something here? Or must I switch my Node view into a Comment view?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume here that `field_last_name` is a field you added yourself to the account fields. I tested using just the user name, and got it to work fine using the following relationships (starting from a Node):

1. From the node to all comments: was called "Comments of the node using field: comment" here
2. And then from the comment to the author: just called "Author" here in the Comment category

Then I added the "Name" field (User category), and Bob was my proverbial uncle.

Comment: Ahh, we're making progress. Do you know how to filter the comments to only the latest ones are displayed?

Comment: Depends on how exactly you mean "Latest ones". Most logical would be to sort by Comment Post Date descending, and only display the top x items (in the pager section).